# Function pointer trouble

Tags: c++, function-pointers, type-mismatch

I have a simple code

```
class a{
public:
     double (a::*fun)(const double &) const;
     //
     ....
     //
};

class b{
public:
    a c1;
    double f(const double & x) const{
        return 0;
    }

    b(){
        c1.fun = f;
    }
};
```

It mean class "a" must work with functions of a certain type, and his work does not depend of this function realization (for example algebraic interpolation). I want make parameter of class - function.
But I have some problem. Compiler write

a value of type "int (b::*)(const int &x) const" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int (a::*)(const int &) const"

How it's made correct?

Answer (score 1):

`double (a::*fun)(const double &) const` declares a pointer to a member function of class `a` which return double and takes in `const double&`.

In your example you are trying to assign the function defined in class `b`. that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a template would solve this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Params
{
    double (T::* fun)(const double &) const;
    // ...
};


class B
{
    Params<B> params;

    double f(const double &) const;

public:
    B() : params(&B::f) { }
    // ...
};
```

To invoke the function somewhere in a non-static member function of `B` on the current instance you would say:

```
double d;
(this->*params.fun)(d);
```